# EF Core 6 / Many to many relationship with custom connection table / ORA-00904 : invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

Hey im trying to create a many to many relationship as following:

```cs
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}  
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}  
public class Book2Category
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

The c# classes are exactly the same like the oracle database tables.

My fluent Api `OnModelCreating` method:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Book>(entity =>
    {
       entity.HasMany(b => b.Categories)
             .WithMany(c => c.Books)
             .UsingEntity<Book2Category>(d =>
             {
                d.HasKey(k => new { k.BookId, k.CategoryId});
             });
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>(entity =>
    {
       entity.HasMany(b => b.Books)
             .WithMany(c => c.Categories)
             .UsingEntity<Book2Category>(d =>
             {
                d.HasKey(k => new { k.BookId, k.CategoryId});
             });
    });

}
```

I always get error `"ORA-00904: \"BooksId\": invalid identifier"` because EF Core is trying to execute the following select statement:

```sql
/*some selects before*/
left join (
    select b2c.BookId, b2c.CategoryId, b2c.BooksId, b2c.CategoriesId
        from Book2Category b2c
    /*some more after but unimportant*/
)
```

So it takes the defined Keys `BookId` and `CategoryId` from `OnModelCreating`.

But also it genarates `BooksId` and `CategoriesId` (with an S).
This is autogenerated and comes from the properties defined in classes `Book` and `Category`.

What i want to achieve is to configure the entities in OnModelCreating() that i get rid of the two unnecessary `b2c.BooksId, b2c.CategoriesId`.
I know that there is a name convention for EF Core but i dont want to rename the columns in Book2Category.

Is that possible somehow?

Comment: Try to remove `Book2Category` and let EF Core create this table automatically.

Comment: There is already data in the table that i cant loose. I would prefer a solution where i dont have to make any changes on `Book2Category`